# How to return a specific value in a loop

Tags: loops, common-lisp

I am a complete novice to LISP I have the book Practical Common Lisp by Peter Seibel, but I couldn't find an answer to my question.
So basically how do I get this to return the value of the last ":do"

```
(defun averages (numbers)
 (loop :for i :in numbers :sum i :into x :do (/ x (length numbers))))
```

Please bare in mind that I haven't been doing this very long.
Nor am I very aware of the unwritten do's and don't of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`finally`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/06_agb.htm):

```
(defun averages (numbers)
  (loop :for i :in numbers :sum i :into x
     :finally (return (/ x (length numbers)))))
```

To avoid traversing the list twice, you can do (as suggested by @mark-reed and @joshua-taylor)

```
(defun averages (numbers)
  (loop :for n :in numbers :sum n :into x :count t :into len
     :finally (return (/ x len))))
```

but it will probably not make much difference performance-wise.

PS. You might want to consider [`CLOCC/CLLIB/math.lisp`](https://sourceforge.net/p/clocc/hg/ci/default/tree/src/cllib/math.lisp) for your basic statistical needs.

Comment: Additionally, the `length` call needlessly traverses the list a second time.  I would do this instead: `(loop :for i :in numbers :sum i :into x :sum 1 :into n :finally (return (/ x n)))`

Comment: Changing it to "(return (/ x len)) what is len function being called on?

Comment: It's not a function, it's another variable - added a clause to the loop to add 1 to it on every iteration (`:sum 1 :into` - I used `n`, @sds used `len`)

Comment: No need to `:sum 1 :into len`, either;  you can just `:count i :into n`.  It probably doesn't make much difference, but it makes it clearer that len is just the count of the numbers, rather that (e.g.) a sum of weights for averages.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't make use of advanced features like multiple variables inside the LOOP, it's easy to simplify it:

```
(defun averages (numbers)
  (loop for i in numbers sum i into x
        finally (return (/ x (length numbers)))))
```

Just take advantage that the LOOP form returns the sum:

```
(defun averages (numbers)
  (/ (loop for i in numbers sum i)
     (length numbers)))
```

It might also be useful to check for an empty list of numbers first.